# Fixing alignment of search bar using bootstrap 5.0

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

How can I change the alignment of the search bar and the button to the left continuously after the navbar-brand element? I tried adding `justify-content-start` bootstrap, `text-left` bootstrap classes, but none of them worked. The code snippet is given here:

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-light">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
      <img src="images/logo.png" width="200" />
    </a>
    <form class="d-flex">
      <input class="form-control me-2" type="text" />
      <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

Flex is applied to the children.  You are correct in the `justify-content-start` assumption - just need to add it to the parent container.  Like so:

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-light">
  <div class="container-fluid justify-content-start">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
      <img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAAC0lEQVQYV2NgAAIAAAUAAarVyFEAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="200" height="32" style="outline:1px dotted red" />
    </a>
    <form class="d-flex">
      <input class="form-control me-2" type="text" />
      <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```